# How can I create a table with rally-app-builder in SDK 2.0rc2?

Tags: rally

I need to create a table like this

[image]

I am using the rally-app-builder, and was wondering if there is some way of doing it with that?

I've been looking for hours, and couldn't seem to find something that suited my needs.

Just a side question, was is the best way of developing for rally, is it through the rally-app-builder or what do you guys do?

Answer (score 1):

You should find the getting started guide in the SDK docs helpful:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/getting_started

There is also a walkthrough of using Rally App Builder to build your first app:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/guide/app_builder

This basic grid example should help as well:
https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0rc2/doc/#!/example/Grid